# Bootstrap Modal - Prevent from closing if any other area is selected

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

At the moment when my modal is loaded, if you press away from that modal on another part of the screen the modal will hide by default.

Is there a way to prevent it from doing this?

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/

Answer (score 1):

bind event listener and preventDefault

```
$('#myModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
  if (!data) return e.preventDefault() // stops modal from being hidden
})
```